# use Expression<Func<T,X>> in Linq contains extension

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, linq-expressions

Using the following example i would like to use my `Expression` inside my Contains method, having it pass the query onto sql server using the `EF`.

How can i build this up to work correctly?

```
void Main()
{

    IQueryable<Person> qry = GetQueryableItemsFromDB();
    var filtered = qry.Filter(p=>p.CompanyId);

}

public static class Ext
{
    public static IQueryable<T> Filter<T>(this IQueryable<T> items, Expression<Func<T, int>> resolveCompanyIdExpression)
    {      
        IEnumerable<int> validComps = GetCompanyIdsFromDataBase();        
        var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(          
            Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable),"Contains", new[] { typeof(Company) },
            Expression.Constant(validComps),
            resolveCompanyIdExpression.Body),
            resolveCompanyIdExpression.Parameters[0]);
        return items.Where(exp);  
    }  

    public static IQueryable<T> Filter<T>(this IQueryable<T> items, Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<int>>> resolveCompanyIdExpression)
    {      
        IEnumerable<int> validComps = GetCompanyIdsFromDataBase();        
        //No Idea what to do here ?
    }  
}

public class Person
{
    public int CompanyId {get;set;}
}
```

I know i could pass in the entire predicate but i only want the user to supply how to resolve the Company from the entity in question.

**UPDATE**

I have decided to resolve the companyId rather than the entire company entity, i can get the list of ids in memory and im not fussed if that is IQueryable or just a plain array/IEnumerable

However i get some strange errors :

> An exception occured during the execution of '
>   Extent.Select(o => o).Where(p => (p.Hide
>   = False)).Where(p => (p.Archived = False)).Where(item => System.Int32[].Contains(item.Development.CompanyId))'. See
>   InnerException for more details.

Inner exception is

> Argument expression is not valid

**UPDATE 2**

I have edited the code to reflect what i would really like like to do, not having much luck on finding a solution to this.

Comment: Even if you got this to work the way you have it, you'd be performing a separate round-trip for each item in the list because you're basing your query on the list of objects. You'll need to change your query to start with `validComps`, or get an `IQueryable<T>` from the database and start from there. You'll also need to base your "contains" on the unique IDs of the objects rather than the entire objects.

Comment: Ok it was my typo, that should be `IQueryable<T>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, what you want is expression composition:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Filter<T>(IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, int>> getCompanyId) {
    IEnumerable<int> validCompanyIds = GetCompanyIdsFromDatabase();
    Expression<Func<int, bool>> filterByCompanyId = id => validCompanyIds.Contains(id);

    // these generics will actually be inferred, I've just written them to be explicit
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> composed = filterByCompanyId.Compose<T, int, bool>(getCompanyId);
    return query.Where(composed);
}
```

Below is the implementation of the Compose() extension method on expression:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Composes two lambda expressions f(y) and g(x), returning a new expression representing f(g(x)).
    /// This is useful for constructing expressions to pass to functions like Where(). If given x => x.Id and id => ids.Contains(id),
    /// for example, you can create the expression x => ids.Contains(x.Id), which could be passed to Where() for an IQueryable of x's type
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TIn">The input of g</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TIntermediate">The output of g and the input of f</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TOut">The output of f</typeparam>
    /// <param name="f">The outer function</param>
    /// <param name="g">The inner function</param>
    /// <returns>A new lambda expression</returns>
    public static Expression<Func<TIn, TOut>> Compose<TIn, TIntermediate, TOut>(this Expression<Func<TIntermediate, TOut>> f, Expression<Func<TIn, TIntermediate>> g)
    {
        // The implementation used here gets around EF's inability to process Invoke expressions. Rather than invoking f with the output of g, we
        // effectively "inline" g by replacing all instances of f's parameter with g's body and creating a new lambda with the rebound body of f and
        // the parameters of g
        var map = f.Parameters.ToDictionary(p => p, p => g.Body);            
        var reboundBody = ParameterRebinder.ReplaceParameters(map, f.Body);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TIn, TOut>>(reboundBody, g.Parameters);
        return lambda;
    }

public class ParameterRebinder : ExpressionVisitor
        { 
            private readonly Dictionary<ParameterExpression, Expression> Map;

            public ParameterRebinder(Dictionary<ParameterExpression, Expression> map)
            {
                this.Map = map ?? new Dictionary<ParameterExpression, Expression>();
            }

            public static Expression ReplaceParameters(Dictionary<ParameterExpression, Expression> map, Expression exp)
            {
                return new ParameterRebinder(map).Visit(exp);
            } 

            protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
            {
                Expression replacement;
                if (this.Map.TryGetValue(node, out replacement))
                {
                    return this.Visit(replacement);
                }
                return base.VisitParameter(node);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try Expression.Compile() method:

```
return items.Where(item => validComps.Contains(resolveCompanyExpression.Compile()(item))).AsQueryable();
```

Comment: I dont think that `.Compile` will work as an Expression, it returns `Func<T,Company>` for me and does not work when passing query to database.

Comment: perhaps this link might help: http://rapidapplicationdevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/03/expression-trees-why-linq-to-sql-is.html

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the `items` parameter an `IQueryable`? If so, try this:

```
public static IQueryable<T> FilterByCompany<T>(this IQueryable<T> items, Expression<Func<T, Company>> resolveCompanyExpression)
    where T : EntityBase
{
    IQueryable<Company> validComps = GetCompaniesFromDataBase();

    var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable),
            "Contains",
            new[] { typeof(Company) },
            Expression.Constant(validComps),
            resolveCompanyExpression.Body
        ),
        resolveCompanyExpression.Parameters[0]
    );
    return items.Where(exp);
}
```

Comment: In the OP's example, `this` is a List<>.