# Creating a dynamic EF filter that builds a LINQ Where equals/contains statement for any string entity property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expression, iqueryable

In short, I'm looking to do [what this guy did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654754/is-there-a-way-to-parameterize-method-in-a-linq-query), but with Entity Framework 6.

Implementing the proposed solution results in the error **"The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities."** Since the proposed solution uses `Invoke`, this is obviously an issue.

I understand that there's a way to harness [a custom Compose method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12755768/3986790) to rewrite the expression tree without using `Invoke`, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Here's what I'm trying to write.

I build an `IQueryable<TEntity>` dynamically using a `QueryParameters` object that's just a bag of properties to use for the WHERE clauses. `TEntity` is a standard code-first EF entity with data annotations all over the place. The query contruction looks something like this:

```cs
IQueryable<TEntity> query = Context.Set<TEntity>();

if (queryParams == null)
    return query;

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(queryParams.FirstName))
{
    if (queryParams.ExactSearch)
    {
        query = query.Where(x => x.FirstName == queryParams.FirstName);
    }
    else
    {
        if (queryParams.PreferStartsWith)
        {
            query = query.Where(
                x => x.FirstName.ToLower()
                    .StartsWith(
                        queryParams.FirstName
                            .ToLower()));
        }
        else
        {            
            query = query.Where(
                x => x.FirstName.ToLower()
                    .Contains(
                        queryParams.FirstName
                            .ToLower()));
        }
    }
}

// ... repeat for all of queryParams' string props.
// DateTime, int, bool, etc have their own filters.
```

This gets repeated for every query parameter for a string field to be queried. Obviously, this results in a lot of repeated code. I would love to be able to write a filter with a signature like this:

```cs
public static IQueryable<TEntity> Search<TEntity>(
    this IQueryable<TEntity> query,
    Expression<Func<TEntity, string>> fieldExpression,
    string searchValue,
    bool exactSearch = true,
    bool useStartsWithOverContains = false) {...}
```

Which I can then consume like this:

```cs
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(queryParams.FirstName))
{
    query = query.Search(
                x => x.FirstName,
                queryParams.FirstName,
                queryParams.ExactSearch,
                queryParams.PreferStartsWith);
}
```

The closest I've come a definition for that extension method is the below, but as mentioned, it produces that "'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities" error:

```cs
public static IQueryable<TEntity> Search<TEntity>(
    this IQueryable<TEntity> query,
    Expression<Func<TEntity, string>> fieldExpression,
    string searchValue,
    bool exactSearch = true,
    bool useStartsWithOverContains = false)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchValue))
        return query;

    searchValue = searchValue.Trim();

    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression;

    if (exactSearch)
    {
        var x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "x");

        var left = Expression.Invoke(fieldExpression, x);
        var right = Expression.Constant(searchValue);
        var equalityExpression = Expression.Equal(left, right);

        expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(
            equalityExpression,
            x);
    }
    else
    {
        searchValue = searchValue.ToLower();
        var x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "x");

        var fieldToLower = Expression.Call(
            Expression.Invoke(fieldExpression, x),
            typeof(string).GetMethod(
                "ToLower",
                Type.EmptyTypes));
        var searchValueExpression =
            Expression.Constant(searchValue);

        var body = Expression.Call(
            fieldToLower,
            typeof(string).GetMethod(
                useStartsWithOverContains ? "StartsWith" : "Contains",
                new[] { typeof(string) }),
            searchValueExpression);

        expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(
            body,
            x);
    }

    return query.Where(expression);
}
```

I started to include the [Compose method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12207396/3986790) I mentioned, but I got lost really quickly, and thus removed it.

Open to any guidance! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *much* easier to do by composing expressions than it is by trying to manually construct the expressions every single time.  It's faster to write, *so* much less error prone, and actually ends up with code you can actually read at the end of it.  All you need to do is write the code for how you use the value in the composed expression, which you already have from your original code.

```
public static IQueryable<TEntity> Search<TEntity>(
    this IQueryable<TEntity> query,
    Expression<Func<TEntity, string>> fieldExpression,
    string searchValue,
    bool exactSearch = true,
    bool useStartsWithOverContains = false)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchValue))
        return query;

    searchValue = searchValue.Trim();

    if (exactSearch)
    {
        return query.Where(fieldExpression.Compose(field => field == searchValue));
    }
    else if (useStartsWithOverContains)
    {
        return query.Where(fieldExpression.Compose(field => field.StartsWith(searchValue.ToLower())));
    }
    else
    {
        return query.Where(fieldExpression.Compose(field => field.Contains(searchValue.ToLower())));
    }
}
```

Note you should probably go with an enum for "Comparison" or something like that, rather than having two booleans.  For example, right now someone can say that they don't want an exact sure but that they do want to use starts with.  Just have one parameter with the three options.

Comment: Thanks for your response, though I'm not quite sure how to use it. What Compose method are you using? The one I reference in my question takes 2 arguments. I did change my two Booleans to an enum; thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Here's the signature of that method, the one I'm using: `public static Expression<Func<TIn, TOut>> Compose<TIn, TIntermediate, TOut>(this Expression<Func<TIntermediate, TOut>> f, Expression<Func<TIn, TIntermediate>> g)`

Comment: @J.D.Mallen I'd suggest reversing the arguments.  It makes no sense to specify what you do with the intermediate result before specifying what it is.   I didn't rigorously test if your implementation of compose was working, but [here's mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37602870/1159478) if you'd rather use it.